# unprotect excel workbook #2

Tags: c#, excel

I have one excel which is password protected. i am trying to add one macro to this excel..
My code is

```
   oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, 0, false, 5, "xyz", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true);

    //oModule = oMOD.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook");

    oBook.Unprotect("xyz");

    // Create a new VBA code module.
    oModule =
    oBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
    oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

When i run this i am getting this error "Can't perform operation since the project is protected."

Any help how to get rid of this error

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem. The solution is not found, but found workaround:

try to switch Application's `Visibility` property

```
oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName, 0, false, 5, "xyz", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true);


oExcel.Visible= true;
oExcel.Visible = false;

oBook.Unprotect("xyz");
```

I really don`t know how it works (seems like a bug), but this simple two lines of code helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: HI,
When i add above two lines of code i am getting the following error

'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility' and no extension method 'Visibility' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' could be found

Comment: sorry: oExcel.Visible = true; oExcel.Visible = false;

Comment: Hi i am still getting the same error "Can't perform operation since the project is protected" when i add these two lines of code..